# how to create a file like the log file, when this log file is updated, then the copy file is also updated?

Tags: file, logging, centos

show me how to create a file like the log file in centos, when this log file is updated, then the copy file is also updated.

help me to  do that

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use symbolic link.

```
ln -s logfile copy_of_logfile
```

Comment: when logfile's content is added,then copy_of_logfile's content is also added ==> ok, but logfile's content is deleted, I want copy_of_logfile's content is NOT deleted.. please tell me how to do that..